# XSockets.NET 4.0 - new controller instance created on method call

Tags: xsockets.net

After upgrading my .NET server and client projects to 4.0 RC
I get NullReference exceptions because my custom State object is null.
I instantiate the state property in OnOpen event handler, but inside the method body of the first call it is already null.

I have checked in debugger and see that this.GetHashCode() returns different values
in OnOpen event handler and in method, which means it is a different instance.

Is it a known issue? I assume it is very basic behavior and probably I have missed something during upgrade to new version.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using alias there is a bug (as you have found out).
The workaround is to either use the class name of the controller or only have alias in lower casing.

In your case using

```
[XSocketMetadata(PluginAlias = "test")]
```

would work.

Regards
Uffe

Answer (score 2):

I managed to understand the problem. It happens when using PluginAlias.
    [XSocketMetadata(PluginAlias =
When attribute is removed and client uses full controller name everything works as expected 
and GetHashCode returns same id.

I pushed the replication code to GitHub:
https://github.com/amichel/PlayWithXSockets/tree/ReproduceBugs